# Oracle SQL - Joining tables to include one column to the other (vice versa)

Tags: sql, oracle, join

**These are my sample tables, columns and records...**

```
Table:           tbl1
         -----------------------
Columns: ID | DEPT | WK | MANHRS
Records: 01    A     1      8 
         02    A     2      2

Table: tbl2
--------------------------------
Columns: ID | DEPT | WK | WAGES
Records: 01     A    1      3
         02     A    2      5
```

Scenario:
I want to have a result where two tables are joined and MANHRS and WAGES columns are both together in the result set.

```
Expected output of the result table: 
Columns:  ID | DEPT | WK | MANHRS | WAGES
          01    A      1    8         3
          02    A      2    2         5
```

I tried UNION but didn't get my expected result. :(

How to do this?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  What issue are you having?  What have you tried?

Comment: I tried UNION but didn't get my expected result. :(

Comment: Try again with `JOIN` and put the query into the question (you can edit the question).

Comment: I tried it. It works. Thank you Gordon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to write the query is:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.WAGES  
FROM tbl1 t1 JOIN
     tbl2 t2
     ON t1.DEPT = t2.DEPT and t1.WK = t2.WK;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- I'm not sure if `ID` should be in the `JOIN` conditions.
- If you want all rows in both tables, but some might be missing, then use `FULL JOIN`.

You can write the query with the `USING` clause:

```
SELECT ID, DEPT, WK, t1.MANHRS, t2.WAGES  
FROM tbl1 t1 JOIN
     tbl2 t2
     USING (ID, DEPT, WK);
```

This is particularly useful if you are using a `FULL JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you! I will take note of the 'proper join syntax'. I am using commas when joining and have the keys in the where clauses. I also used (+) for left/right joins. I am not sure why it is not a best practice. Could you please enlighten me?

Comment: @boombox2014 . . . I think the documentation is pretty clear on the subject:  "Oracle recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax rather than the Oracle join operator. "  (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries006.htm#SQLRF52353)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you should join by DEPT and WK:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.WAGES  
FROM tbl1 t1, tbl2 t2
where t1.DEPT = t2.DEPT and t1.WK = t2.WK
```

Comment: Don't answer a question with archaic `JOIN` syntax!